# FirstAsync с условием поиска C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать FirstAsync, чтобы можно было получить первый элемент по условию. Так не работает

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> FindFirstAsync(Func<TEntity, Boolean> predicate) =>
    await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstAsync<TEntity>(predicate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего, чтобы объявить [универсальный метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/twcad0zb.aspx), нужно сделать так:

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> 
  FindFirstAsync<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, Boolean> predicate)
```

Т.е., `<TEntity>` должно быть не только в типе метода, но и в его имени.

Далее. Из вашего кода не понятно, откуда метод должен узнать, что такое `_dbContext`. Хотя, конечно, это может быть поле/свойство класса, к которому принадлежит метод.

Далее. Я так понимаю, вы хотите расширить класс Set, чтобы можно было сделать так:

```
await SomeContext.SomeSet.FindFirstAsync(s => Condition(s));
```

В таком случае, метод следует описывать таким образом (использую "старую" запись для повышения читаемости):

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> 
  FindFirstAsync<TEntity>(this Set<TEntity> Source, Func<TEntity, Boolean> predicate) 
{
    return await Source.FirstAsync(entity => predicate(entity));
}
```

После чего у вас появится возможность вызывать метод `FindFirstAsync` у любого экземпляра `Set<T>` способом, описаным выше. Это называется [метод расширения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb383977.aspx)

---

Однако на самом деле вопрос в другом: зачем вообще в данном случае объявлять метод `FindFirstAsync`? Вот `FirstAsync` делает то же самое:

```
await someContext.SomeSet.FirstAsync(s => Condition(s));
```

Или более конкретный пример:

```
await someContext.SomeSet.FirstAsync(s => s.Id == Id_From_Variable);
```